# arangodb replication applier stopped with error 1413: no start tick

Tags: arangodb

4:32 AM (2 minutes ago)

i followed the replication (master-slave) setup guide, and got data replicated fine, but the applier is stopped with the following error. i searched manual and googled without finding much other than the error message itself. really appreciate if you could provide some clues as how to troubleshoot this. thanks!

```
arangosh [_system]> require("org/arangodb/replication").applier.state();
{ 
  "state" : {
    "running" : false,
    "lastAppliedContinuousTick" : null,
    "lastProcessedContinuousTick" : null,
    "lastAvailableContinuousTick" : null,
    "progress" : {
      "time" : "2014-04-15T20:20:13Z",
      "message" : "applier stopped",
      "failedConnects" : 0
    },
    "totalRequests" : 5,
    "totalFailedConnects" : 0,
    "totalEvents" : 0,
    "lastError" : {
      "time" : "2014-04-15T20:20:13Z",
      "errorMessage" : "no start tick",
      "errorNum" : 1413
    },
    "time" : "2014-04-15T20:37:50Z"
  },
  "server" : {
    "version" : "2.0.4",
    "serverId" : "83323931320193"
  },
  "endpoint" : "tcp://master:8529",
  "database" : "_system"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might happen if you start the applier for the very first time without specifying a tick. Use

`require("org/arangodb/replication").applier.start(1)`

instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. Really appreciate your help. Yes, I got your googlegroup reply as well.